# apple accelerate framework -- constrain magnitude without losing absolute value

Tags: ios, accelerate-framework, vdsp

I'd like to use apple's accelerate for efficient clipping of an audio signal. If the signal is greater than 1 or less than -1, I'd like to make it equal to 1 or -1. `vDSP_vmaxmg` looks like it's almost what i'm looking for, but not quite. The documentation says it does this:

*Each element of output vector C is the larger of the magnitudes of corresponding values from input vectors A and B.*

So it looks like the output of `vDSP_vmaxmg` will always be absolute values of the input, will always be positive. Can the accelerate framework help me if I want to preserve the absolute value of the output of a signal, but constrain the magnitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `vDSP_vclip( )`:

```
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

...

float min = -1.0f;
float max =  1.0f;
vDSP_vclip(inputBuffer, inputStride, &min, &max,
           outputBuffer, outputStride, length);
```

Comment: Duh. Right there in front of me. Thanks!